# Sheets - Split number right to left to maxium of 5 characters

Tags: google-sheets

If given a column of numbers and characters such as this.

```
2
x73374690x
```

How can I turn that into this using Google Sheets.
I tried using numbers as the delimters in split without success

```
=iferror(SPLIT(C13,"0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9",FALSE),"NA")
```

Expected output

```
NA  NA  NA  NA  2
4   6   9   0   x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula will work for big string:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(RIGHT(A1,5),REPT("(.)?",5))`

---

and smth like this should handle all cases:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(REPT("-",5-len(RIGHT(A1,5)))&RIGHT(A1,5),REPT("(.)?",5))`

The result:

```
x73374690x  4   6   9   0   x
2           -   -   -   -   2
222         -   -   2   2   2
222x        -   2   2   2   x
```

Comment: NIce solution, trying to understand this REGEXTRACT better but docs a little thin. Thank heaps